# Unable to get expected speed up with cython (search in a list of strings)

Tags: python, cython

I am unable to speed up computations with my **cythonized version** of a function **bulk_phone_finder** defined below (that uses phonenumbers pypi library) to  :

```
from phonenumbers import PhoneNumberMatcher
from phonenumbers.phonenumberutil import SUPPORTED_REGIONS

def bulk_phone_finder(l):
    return [get_phonenumbers(content) for content in l]

def get_phonenumbers(content):
    return set([m.raw_string for cc in SUPPORTED_REGIONS for m in PhoneNumberMatcher(content,
 cc)
            ])
```

I am a bit new to cython , but i managed to make a cython equivalent function :

```
# cython: c_string_type=unicode, c_string_encoding=utf8
from phonenumbers import PhoneNumberMatcher
from phonenumbers.phonenumberutil import SUPPORTED_REGIONS
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.string cimport string
from libcpp.set cimport set as c_set


cpdef c_set[string] _SUPPORTED_REGIONS = SUPPORTED_REGIONS

cdef get_phonenumbers(string content):
    res = set()
    cdef string cc
    cdef string raw_string
    for cc in _SUPPORTED_REGIONS :
        for m in PhoneNumberMatcher(content, cc):
            raw_string = m.raw_string
            res.add(raw_string)
    return res


def bulk_phone_finder(l):
    res=[]
    cpdef c_set[string] int_res
    cpdef string content
    for content in l :
        int_res= get_phonenumbers(content)
        res.append(int_res)
    return res
```

this cython .pyx file is compiled with the following setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup( ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
            "bulk_phonenumber_finder",
            sources=["bulk_phonenumber_finder.pyx"],
            # extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11"],
            language="c++"
     )))
```

But i'm unable to get the speed up as :

```
lines=["0256985412"]*100

# cython version
In [6]: %timeit bulk_phonenumber_finder.bulk_phone_finder(lines)
9.39 s ± 363 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# python version
In [8]: %timeit bulk_phone_finder(lines)
9.44 s ± 213 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Do you have any advice to speed up my function bulk_phone_finder ?

Any help is more than welcome ,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Every time you use a C++ data type, Cython will have to make copies of the data in C++ format to fill it, and then will have to copy it again to get the data back to Python., These are probably making your code slower. This doesn't look like code that's going to speed up too much...

Comment: Any idea how to change then my code accordingly to get a speed up ? I'm a bit new to cython , thanks again

Comment: I can't see many opportunities to speed it up. Have you tried compiling your Python version with Cython? I would expect that to give a small speedup. Have you profiled it (probably easier done on the uncompiled Python version)? I'd guess the real work is all in the library you're using and so there's very little you can do in your code.

Comment: you need to `cdef` all your loop variables

Comment: but if you use a library written in pure Python, you defeat the purpose of Cython, as it will have to make a call to a python code, from within compiled C code. Either you rewrite the function in Cython, or try to cythonize the library ^^'